# for文のvar宣言 ／ 配列を追加する際、pushを使用せずlengthを使用するメリットは何かあるのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

**質問1.for文のvar宣言について**
・下記ループでどちらが良いとかありますか？
・それぞれメリットデメリットがあれば教えてください
・何れにしても、for文の中でvar宣言するよりは良い？

例a

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < num; i++) {}
```

例b

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {}
```

---

**質問2.配列への追加について**
・下記コードは、配列へ追加していると思うのですが、どうしてpushを使用していないのでしょうか？
・lengthを使用する理由(メリット)としては何が考えられるでしょうか？
・最後に追加してもインデックスを指定して追加しても、結局は同じ結果を得られるから気にする必要はない？

```
var hoge    = [];
function userFunc(num) {
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < num; i++) {
        hoge[hoge.length] = new Hoge();
    }
}
```

Comment: タイトルを併記するぐらい独立した質問のようですから、2つの質問は別々に投稿した方がよいのでは…。一度に投稿された理由はなんでしょうか？

Comment: 一度に投稿した理由は、分からないコードがあったので質問を書いている内、疑問が増えていったため(それだけ)です。二つに分けた方が良かったですね。別々に再投稿しようかと思ったのですが、既に回答いただいいているため、次からはなるべく分けて投稿するようにしたいと思います

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScriptの変数のスコープは関数単位](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)です。`var`に関しては関数内のどこに記述しても意味は同じです。ですので残りは`i = 0`がいつ実行されるかの違いでしかなく、for前・for内のどちらに記述するかは好みで判断してください。

---

[JavaScriptの配列](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)は特殊です。仕様上、配列のインデックスは数値ではなく文字列なので例えば`hoge["abc"]`とすることも可能です。
その上で、[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)は複数の引数を受け配列に追加する関数ですので、１引数に限定するのであれば`hoge[index]`とインデックスアクセスの方が高速化されるのかも？と考えることはできます。
と答えはしましたが質問2に関してはメリットはよくわかりません。

Comment: pushの方が速い、という話もあるみたいですね。手元では違いがわかりませんでしたが…… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value